# org-mode agenda view matching tag and todo state

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to create an agenda view with `org-agenda-custom-commands`, which will connect capabilities `todo-tree` and `tags-tree`.

That's what I want to achieve, this sparse tree suited to such a search

```
C-c / m
```

JOB+TODO="NEXT"

Comment: I would suggest that you read through the advanced searching tutorial from the org-mode manual, try some of those advanced searches yourself, and then (if you still need help) revise your question to include the advanced searches that you have tried and why they do not meet your specific needs: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question. The problem is not to create advanced queries (I can create a proper sparse tree by C-c / m). I do not know how to convert it to the configuration in .emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer. In .emacs I must add:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
'(
("j" "JOB next" tags-tree "JOB+TODO=\"NEXT\"" )))
```